# file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: php, file-upload, file-get-contents

Neste código que estou a criar para fazer o upload de imagens de perfil para o imgur

```
if (isset($_POST['uploadprofileimg'])) {
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['profileimg']['tmp_name']));

    $options = array('http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer sdf541gs6df51gsd1bsb16etb16teg1etr1ge61g\n",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'content' => $image
    ));

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";

    $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, FALSE, $context);
}
```

Está-me a dar esta informação:

> Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in C:\WebServer\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs\html\www\SocialNetwork\my-account.php on line 17

A linha 17 é a que tem o response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, FALSE, $context);

Não estou a perceber o porquê de me estar a dar esse "erro"

Já experimentei adicionar "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n", e"Connection: close"
mas sem sucesso

Comment: Já experimentou concatenar o header com o content-type? Me parece que você está usando virgula.

Comment: Sim, o que fiz foi 
    'header' => "Authorization: Bearer sdf541gs6df51gsd1bsb16etb16teg1etr1ge61g\n".
    "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n",
mas mesmo assim nada

Comment: mas no seu exemplo tem uma virgula e não um ponto.

Comment: Li mal a resposta e quando tentei editar não me deixou. Consegui resolver desta forma
    'header' => "Authorization: Bearer e9e87b8334e9dafb3b14f55993b1b1bc4515f7c4\n".
                       "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

Answer (score 2):

O erro está na formação do $options. Content-Type não é um parametro válido.
Ele é um cabeçalho do http e o lugar certo dele seria no $options['header'];

Observe a concatenação da string.

Segue:

```
if (isset($_POST['uploadprofileimg'])) {
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['profileimg']['tmp_name']));

    $options = array('http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' =>
            "Authorization: Bearer sdf541gs6df51gsd1bsb16etb16teg1etr1ge61g\n" . // ---
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'content' => $image
    ));

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";

    $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, FALSE, $context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema no seu código é que você está adicionando um parâmetro a mais no array ao invés de concatenar.

Mude este código:

```
$options = array('http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer sdf541gs6df51gsd1bsb16etb16teg1etr1ge61g\n",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'content' => $image
    ));
```

Por este:

```
 $options = array('http' => array(
            'method' => "POST",
            'header' => 
"Authorization: Bearer sdf541gs6df51gsd1bsb16etb16teg1etr1ge61g\n" .
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'content' => $image
        ));
```

**Nota**: A mudança está apenas na virgula que estava no final da linha do parâmetro header. Mudei o trecho `etr1ge61g\n" , "Content-` por este `etr1ge61g\n" . "Content-`